# What is the probability of getting a known (but random) outcome in a coin toss?

Tags: probability

Pretty dumb question I guess. Say I have a known outcome such as (H, T, T) or (T, H, T). If I toss the coin thrice, what is the probability of getting exactly this outcome? We have 2^3 = 8 possible known outcomes. An explanation of how to approach this problem will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explicitly, the 8 possible coin toss outcomes are HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT.  Each of these outcomes is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of seeing a specific sequence of $N$ fair coin tosses is simply $1/2^N$. For every toss, you have a 50% probability of succeeding, and since the tosses are independent, you just multiply the probabilities together.

Alternatively, you can think of it as enumerating all the possible outcomes - there are $2^N$. All the outcomes are equally likely, and only one of those outcomes fits the sequence you need, so the probability of success is $1/2^N$.

Note that this assumes you need a particular *sequence* of results, so that HTH is distinct from THH or HHT.